# Need help for Auto user name and time

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Excel in which I need to get Auto user name and Time for two entry's example
1. If I insert a value in column 2 I need user name and time at cell "A" and "O"
2. In same Excel sheet again for the entry at Column(7) I need date and Username at cell "I" and "N"

My code working for single point and I am confuse how to use twice.

Check the code I try and advise

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = 0 Then
                With c.EntireRow
                    .Cells(1, "A").Value = Now()
                    '.Cells(1, "B").Value = Date
                    .Cells(1, "O").Value = Environ("username")
                End With
            End If
        End If

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(7))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = 0 Then
                With c.EntireRow
                    .Cells(1, "I").Value = Now()
                    '.Cells(1, "B").Value = Date
                    .Cells(1, "N").Value = Environ("username")
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: ① Your first line of code is missing but important for us. • ② Please read [mcve] and provide a complete example of your issue including sample input and desired output data. Screenshots might help here too.

Comment: yes my first lien is "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, this is working for me:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1) = vbNullString Then Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now()
        If Me.Cells(Target.Row, 15) = vbNullString Then Me.Cells(Target.Row, 15) = Environ("username")
    ElseIf Target.Column = 7 Then
        If Me.Cells(Target.Row, 9) = vbNullString Then Me.Cells(Target.Row, 9) = Now()
        If Me.Cells(Target.Row, 14) = vbNullString Then Me.Cells(Target.Row, 14) = Environ("username")
    End If

End Sub
```

Thought I'm not sure if you want the logging to be on the same row you are inserting data or rewrite it always on the same cell.

Comment: Note that this fails if `Target` is not a single cell but a range. This breaks the ability of copy/paste ranges. To avoid that use `Intersect` like the OP already did correctly! • And do it in two distinct `If` statements. `Target` can contain column 2 and 7 **at the same time** which is not covered by `ElseIf`.

Comment: I've never learn to use the intersect @Pᴇʜ how would I use it here? `If intersect(Me.Columns(2), Target) Then` this works if its on column 2, but wont work to any other column.

Comment: Just exactly as the OP did. He did everything correct (including looping through the intersected range that is missing in your code too) except that he exit sub if `Target` is not column 2 and therefore never reaches the second test for column 7. See my answer.

Comment: Supper Damian working exact what i expect, thanks a lot

Comment: @MastanShaik you should check PEH's answer, mine won't work if you paste multiple cells.

Comment: @Damian,Thanks for your advise and we donot paste multiple cells,but the thing is when other user overwrite the cell,original user name getting change,it should not happen,that is the requirement

Comment: @MastanShaik I don't get that, so If you change cell B2 and someone else changes later that cell, what is your goal? What should A2 be?

Comment: @Damian,Yes ,if some one (other user) want to edit the data inserted in B2 as you said,First user name, who inserted the data should be remain,But here, user name get changing.

Comment: @MastanShaik then you just need to check wether the cell is empty or not, check out my answer, I edited it with the checking.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic line is `If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` because if `Target` is not in column 2 it exits sub and will never reach the second test for column 7.

So use `If Not rng Is Nothing Then` instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                If Len(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = 0 Then
                    With c.EntireRow
                        .Cells(1, "A").Value = Now()
                        '.Cells(1, "B").Value = Date
                        .Cells(1, "O").Value = Environ("username")
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End If

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(7))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                If Len(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = 0 Then
                    With c.EntireRow
                        .Cells(1, "I").Value = Now()
                        '.Cells(1, "B").Value = Date
                        .Cells(1, "N").Value = Environ("username")
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Supper PEH,working exact what i expect, thanks a lot

Comment: Dear PEH,thanks for your help,a small doubt, how we work in excel is ,First, Column 2 was filled then we get auto date and user name,Second, column 7 was filled then we need auto date and user name again,here what happen is,if Column 2 filled,first part of code working correct,but not 2nd part,if Column 2 not filled then only column 7 code working,any comments?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Probably you need to explain it in your original question and add a screenshot or something to explain the issue better.